# When would you replace the Message of an Exchange instead of the Body of a Message in Apache Camel?

Tags: spring-boot, replace, apache-camel, message

I'm working with Apache Camel and usually **only replace the body** of the message after transformations or set some headers and properties.

[image]

**What is a valid use case for replacing the entire message with a new one instead of just the body?**

Answer (score 1):

Changing the message implementation is only something custom components may do if they work with a message that has special capabilities.

As an end user you just work directly with the headers and body as-is